# Rails 5 ActionCable Not Receiving Data received method not called

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

When I post a new comment in the product page, an alert should appear to all the users that are logged in and in that page, also the comment should appear without refreshing the page.

When there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel ProductChannel the function received in product.js should be called, but instead nothing happens. Any ideas what could be the problem?

```
App.product = App.cable.subscriptions.create("ProductChannel", {
  connected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received: function(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    $('.alert.alert-info').show().delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
    $('.product-reviews').prepend(data.comment);
    $("#average-rating").attr('data-score', data.average_rating);
    refreshRating();
  },

  listen_to_comments: function(){
    return this.perform('listen', {
      product_id: $("[data-product-id]").data("product-id")
    });
  }
});

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  App.product.listen_to_comments();
});
```

product_channel.rb

```
class ProductChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # stream_from "some_channel"
    # stream_from "product_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def listen(data)
    stop_all_streams
    stream_for data["product_id"]
  end
end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = @product.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        ProductChannel.broadcast_to @product.id, comment: CommentsController.render(partial: 'comments/comment', locals: {comment: @comment, current_user: current_user}), average_rating: @product.average_rating
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Review was created successfully.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @product, alert: 'Review was not saved successfully.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Also I get this error Unable to process ProductChannel#listen({"product_id"=>9})

Comment: Any luck? I'm getting that generic error as well.

Comment: Did you end up figuring out a solution?